# How to update a value in core data?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to update a flashcards score every time it the flash card is studied, but the score isn't saving. What am I doing wrong?

```
do {

    fetchedCards = try context.fetch(Cards.fetchRequest())

    for cards in fetchedCards {
        if(termLabel.text == cards.term){
            cards.score = score
            ad.saveContext()
            continue
        }
    }

} catch {

}


let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Comment: Edited: 1. How are `ad` and `context` being related/connected to an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` instance? You need to show that part as well. 2. Also is it get saved in memory but not in storage? To find out about that, please do `print("\This is before saveContext (cards.score)"` before you call `saveContext()` and check if `score` contains the updated value or not. If its getting updated then it means your code is reaching that point and it **is** getting updated in memory but perhaps just not in storage...3. `catch` the error if something is happening

Comment: The issue was score did not update, I set score = 10 before cards.score = score and it saved. thank you